# Dudas sobre arreglos en PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7

> ~ Cargar dos arreglos de enteros de N y M posiciones. 
>   ~ Se pide generar un programa que produzca la intersección entre los dos arreglos.

```
a = []
b = []
n1 = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de elementos del primer arreglo: "))
n2 = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de elementos del segundo arreglo: "))
for i in range(0,n1):
    a.append(int(input("Ingrese un numero para primer vector: ")))
for i in range(0,n2):
    b.append(int(input("Ingrese un numero para segundo vector: ")))
```

Buenas, estoy empezando a programar en python y me trabe en este ejercicio. Mi inconveniente es la interseccion entre el arreglo a y b. Tengo que sacar los elementos que tengan en comun ambos vectores pero no tengo idea como hacerlo. Pense en juntar ambos arreglos en uno mismo y preguntar si hay mas numeros iguales pero creo que se los elementos anteriores van a tomar nuevas posiciones, lo que no quiero. Que condicion deberia pedir para que me saque los numeros repetidos?

Comment: ¿Se te permite usar el tipo de datos "conjunto" (`set`)? En ese caso sería trivial. Basta convertir ambas listas a `set` y usar la operación `intersection()` que los conjuntos te dan. Si no, lo más sencillo es iterar por una de las listas y comprobar si cada elemento está en la otra lista. Si es así lo añades a la lista "intersección". Comprobar si un elemento dado está en una lista es inmediato, pues python te admite la expresión `if elemento in lista: ...`

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que a y b son tus listas, solo hace falta recorrer una de ellas y comparar si cada elemento está en la otra

```
inter = []
for i in a:
     if i in b:
         inter.append(i)
 return Inter
```

Answer (score 2):

Python ofrece vías muy fáciles de resolver este problema, desde hacer uso de utilidades avanzadas como el tipo de dato `set` , hasta la forma más básica que sería la común para cualquier lenguaje de programación. Intentaré darte algunas respuestas para cada nivel de complejidad, y tú tomas la que mejor te sirva atendiendo a tu dominio del lenguaje.

1. **Tipo de dato `set`**

   set (conjunto) maneja colecciones desordenadas de elementos *únicos*, o sea, asegurándose de que ninguno de estos datos esté repetido. Ofrece facilidades para aplicarle a estos elementos operaciones de teoría de conjuntos, como unión o, en tu caso, intersección.
   En este caso casteo tu lista a `a` a tipo `set`, igual con tu lista `b`, aplico la intersección y vuelvo a castear a tipo `list` para obtener mi respuesta final:

   `respuesta = list(set(a).intersection(set(b)))`
2. **List comprehension**

   Se llama así a una manera dinámica de crear listas en python a partir de la aplicación de ciertos criterios a cada elemento de otro iterable... pero eso te queda de estudio ;)

   `respuesta = [elemento for elemento in a if elemento in b]`

   De esta forma creas una lista a la que agregas cada elemento de la lista a si ese elemento también se encuentra en b.
3. **Ciclo for tradicional**

Esta solución no creo que lleve mucha explicación, Python de por sí se explica solo:

```
respuesta = []
for elemento in a:
    if elemento in b:
        respuesta.append(elemento)
```

O incluso más básico:

```
respuesta = []
for elemento_in_a in a:
    for elemento_in_b in b:
        if elemento_in_a == elemento_in_b:
            respuesta.append(elemento_in_a)
            break  # para que vaya a la siguiente iteración del primer for
```

Intenté ser lo más abarcador posible. Espero que te sirva y que tengas largo paso programando en este magnífico lenguaje.

Comment: Buena respuesta, solo añadiría que los métodos 2 y 3 pueden devolver duplicados, por ejemplo con `a = [1, 1, 3, 5, 7]` y `b = [1, 4, 5]` devolverán `[1, 1, 5]` mientras que el método 1 devolverá `[1, 5]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def superposicion(a,b):
    n1 = len(a)
    n2 = len(b)
    contador = 0

    for valor in range(n1):
        for valor1 in range(n2):
            if a[valor] == b[valor1]:
                contador += 1
    if contador > 0:
        return True, contador
    else:
        return False
```

Prueba con esta función, el `contador` es el número de intersecciones entre ambas listas.

Si necesitas comparar dos listas te aconsejo usar bucles `for` anidados para hacer mucho más fácil el trabajo.

Comment: La respuesta no es muy buena, pues promueve "malas prácticas", tales como el antipatrón de usar índices cuando recorres el array en lugar de usar los valores directamente. Es decir, deberías hacer `for elemento in a:` en lugar de `for indice in range(len(a)):`. Además los nombres de variables no están bien elegidos. Llamas `valor` a lo que sería un índice, típicamente llamado `i` o `j`. Además tienes una instrucción `a[valor]` que no tiene efecto, pues no es asignada. Además la función retorna bien una tupla, bien un booleano, lo que complica la vida a quien la use.